# VirtualDirectory in DotVVM

Tags: dotvvm

I want ask, from which version of DotVVM is support for place application to virtual directory in IIS.

We use 1.1.8 version of DotVVM and it's not work for us.

Thanks

Comment: Running DotVVM apps in a virtual directory is supported. DotVVM should translate all URLs starting with ~/ to the correct URLs within the virtual directory.
Is there anything specific that doesn't work for you?

Comment: I tested over weekend and resolve my problem. Now it works fine but thanks for your comment.